# Kafka consumer and producer throwing error

Tags: apache-kafka

I am getting below error while trying to pass words in Kafka-consumer,
commands with i entered

console-1:(for producer)

```
    export PATH=$PATH:/usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/bin

kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper ip-172-31-20-58.ec2.internal:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic testuday1234

kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list ip-172-31-20-58.ec2.internal:6667 --topic testuday1234
```

console-2: (for consumer)

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/bin
kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic testuday1234 --from-beginning
```

Please help me in resolving these error

Error i am getting in Producer console:

```
[udaychitukula6587@ip-172-31-38-183 ~]$ kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list ip-172-31-20-58.ec2.internal:6667 --topic testuday1234
hi
[2018-05-28 15:27:36,761] WARN Error while fetching metadata [{TopicMetadata for topic testuday1234 ->
No partition metadata for topic testuday1234 due to kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableException}] for topic [testuday1234]: class kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableExcep
tion (kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo)
[2018-05-28 15:27:36,774] WARN Error while fetching metadata [{TopicMetadata for topic testuday1234 ->
No partition metadata for topic testuday1234 due to kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableException}] for topic [testuday1234]: class kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableExcep
tion (kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo)
```

Error i am getting in consumer console:

```
[udaychitukula6587@ip-172-31-38-183 ~]$ kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic testuday123 --from-beginning
{metadata.broker.list=ip-172-31-20-58.ec2.internal:6667,ip-172-31-53-48.ec2.internal:6667,ip-172-31-60-179.ec2.internal:6667, request.timeout.ms=30000, client.id=c
onsole-consumer-63526, security.protocol=PLAINTEXT}
{metadata.broker.list=ip-172-31-20-58.ec2.internal:6667,ip-172-31-53-48.ec2.internal:6667,ip-172-31-60-179.ec2.internal:6667, request.timeout.ms=30000, client.id=c
onsole-consumer-63526, security.protocol=PLAINTEXT}
```

Comment: How many partitions? The error is self-explanatory on the Producer side. There are no leaders for the partition on the topic. Whats the exception on the consumer? I don't see anything.

Answer (score 1):

There is a couple of things that I've noted here.

**First**, in the newer versions (I think from 0.10.1) of Kafka for the console consumer, we need to use `--bootstrap-server` option as opposed to `--zookeeper`. Could you please confirm the version you're using? and also try to run the consumer command with `--bootstrap-server` option?

**Second**, for the producer in such a scenario, I would recommend checking 3 things to confirm where the issue might be:

1. The leader of a Kafka cluster is elected by the zookeeper, so it might be worth checking by running a `zookeeper-client` shell to see if there is an active controller in the Kafka cluster (in the znode path - `/brokers/ids/[brokerId]`).
2. Try running a `Kafka-topics --describe --topic` command to see if the topic has an active leader partition i.e. the `Leader` column in the output of the command should NOT have `None`. I've run into this myself before.
3. The last one is about the port number of the broker, could you please check and confirm if the broker is actually listening on that port. You'll find this information (`listeners` and `advertised.listeners`) in server.properties file on the broker. I found [this post](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/27926/kafka-ambari-alert-configuration-when-not-using-po.html) that you might find useful where the user had a problem with the port 6667.

I hope this helps!